# Improving time complexity of chessboard pattern

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, time-complexity

I have coded up a program to print a chessboard pattern.
It goes like so:
(comments explain the logic and variables)

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int block_size = 8; //block_size * block_size is the size of each block on the board
int dim = 8; //8 blocks on every row or column, each block containing block_size * block_size pixels
int res = dim * block_size; //total number of pixels is res * res (resolution)

int main(){
    int size = 8;
    vector<vector<int> > vec(res);  

    for (int i = 0; i < res; i++) { 

        vec[i] = vector<int>(res); 
        for (int j = 0; j < res; j++) {
            vec[i][j] = 0; 
        }
    }//initialize all pixels to 0
    //int count=0;
    /*
    allocate black or white pixels based on odd/even status of array indices which are picked
    based on multiples of block_size
    ex. i,j = 0,4,8,16...
    pixels are allocated from the starting point of a particular coordinate like so: two for loops for i,j + d 
    where 0<=d<block_size
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < res; i=i+block_size) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < res; j=j+block_size) {
            //cout<<count<<" ";
            //count++;
            //cout<<i/block_size;
            if (int ((i/block_size)%2 == 0)){
                if(int ((j/block_size)%2 == 0)){
                    for(int k=i;k<i+block_size;k++){
                        for (int l=j;l<j+block_size;l++){
                            vec[k][l]=0;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    for(int k=i;k<i+block_size;k++){
                        for (int l=j;l<j+block_size;l++){
                            vec[k][l]=255;
                        }
                    }
                }

                }
                else{
                    if(int ((j/block_size)%2 == 0)){
                    for(int k=i;k<i+block_size;k++){
                        for (int l=j;l<j+block_size;l++){
                            vec[k][l]=255;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    for(int k=i;k<i+block_size;k++){
                        for (int l=j;l<j+block_size;l++){
                            vec[k][l]=0;
                        }
                    }
                }

                }

            }
        }

    cout<<endl;
    /*
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < vec[i].size(); j++) 
            cout << vec[i][j] << " "; 
        cout << endl; 
    }
    */
    string filename = "chessboard.pgm";
    ofstream pgmFile(filename);


    pgmFile << "P2" << endl;
    pgmFile << res << " " << res << endl;
    pgmFile << 255 << endl;


    for(int i=0;i<res;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<res;j++){
            pgmFile << vec[i][j] << " ";
        }
        pgmFile << endl;
    }

    pgmFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program is input into a pgm image which is then written onto a file to view, (Irfanview can be used to view the pgm image).
The algorithm goes like:
--allocate black or white pixels based on odd/even status of array indices which   are picked
    based on multiples of block_size
    ex. i,j = 0,4,8,16...
--pixels are allocated from the starting point of a particular coordinate:2 for loops for i,j + d where d ranges from 0 to block_size, not including block_size
Right now, it looks like the complexity is O(n^4). Any ideas on what steps I can take to reduce the complexity?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't quite follow that this is O(n^4). What is n here? If you're visiting each pixel once or twice, then I don't see how you can expect any complexity improvement on that.

Comment: Hi, by n I mean size of input. Yes, that is true, every pixel is visited only once or twice but I thought maybe there is a more efficient algorithm than the one I have used.

Comment: No, it is not O(N^4). Since you must visit every pixel a fixed number of times, and you are already visiting every pixel a fixed number of times, you cannot improve the complexity. You may be able to improve the *efficiency* though. Efficiency is not the same as complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your time complexity is already optimal. Sure, you're doing a few passes over the input, but that constant is ignored and the complexity boils down to the number of pixels in the image (or O(side_length<sup>2</sup> * block_size<sup>2</sup>) or O(res<sup>2</sup>) or just O(n) if *n* is the image size).

Having said that, there's a lot of repeated code, and you can eliminate the vectors entirely, which makes your space complexity constant.

Here's a re-write, keeping only the essentials:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    int block_size = 8;
    int dim = 8;
    int res = dim * block_size;
    std::ofstream pgm("chessboard.pgm");
    pgm << "P2\n" << res << " " << res << "\n255\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < res; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < res; j++) {
            pgm << ((j / block_size + i / block_size) % 2 ? 255 : 0) << " ";
        }

        pgm << "\n";
    }

    pgm.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Lastly: chess typically has a black square in the bottom-left corner, so you may consider inverting your colors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this (this is full code for board filing in console).

Every pixel is visited once as in your implementation,  complexity is `O(res^2)` too, but looks simpler.

*For `block_size`-s equal to powers of 2, `rx` and `ry` might be calculated through bitwise operations*

```
int main()
{
    int block_size = 4; //block_size * block_size is the size of each block on the board
    int dim = 4; //8 blocks on every row or column, each block containing block_size * block_size pixels
    int res = dim * block_size; //total number of pixels is res * res (resolution)
    vector<vector<int> > vec(res);

    for (int i = 0; i < res; i++) {
        vec[i] = vector<int>(res);
        }

    for (int y = 0; y < res; y++) {
        int ry = ((y % (block_size * 2)) < block_size) ? 0 : 1;
        for (int x = 0; x < res; x++) {
            int rx = ((x % (block_size * 2)) < block_size) ? 0 : 1;
            vec[y][x] = 255 * (ry ^ rx);
            cout << vec[y][x] << "\t";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Simpler approach proposed by  Jarod42:

```
for (int y = 0; y < res; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < res; x++) {
        vec[y][x] = ((y / block_size) + (x / block_size)) % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 255;
```

result for 4x4:

```
0       0       0       0       255     255     255     255     0       0       0       0       255     255     255     255
0       0       0       0       255     255     255     255     0       0       0       0       255     255     255     255
0       0       0       0       255     255     255     255     0       0       0       0       255     255     255     255
0       0       0       0       255     255     255     255     0       0       0       0       255     255     255     255
255     255     255     255     0       0       0       0       255     255     255     255     0       0       0       0
255     255     255     255     0       0       0       0       255     255     255     255     0       0       0       0
255     255     255     255     0       0       0       0       255     255     255     255     0       0       0       0
255     255     255     255     0       0       0       0       255     255     255     255     0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0       255     255     255     255     0       0       0       0       255     255     255     255
0       0       0       0       255     255     255     255     0       0       0       0       255     255     255     255
0       0       0       0       255     255     255     255     0       0       0       0       255     255     255     255
0       0       0       0       255     255     255     255     0       0       0       0       255     255     255     255
255     255     255     255     0       0       0       0       255     255     255     255     0       0       0       0
255     255     255     255     0       0       0       0       255     255     255     255     0       0       0       0
255     255     255     255     0       0       0       0       255     255     255     255     0       0       0       0
255     255     255     255     0       0       0       0       255     255     255     255     0       0       0       0
```

Comment: or something like `vec[y][x] = ((y / block_size) + (x / block_size)) % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 255;` (parity of `block_x + block_y`).

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, this is even simpler

Answer (score 1):

The checkerboard has a nice pattern. It alternates even rows (starting with a black square), and odd rows (starting with a white one). This suggests a natural program structure:

```
    for (row_pair = 0; row_pair < dim / 2; row_pair++) {
        emit_row(something_even);
        emit_row(something_odd);
    }
```

In turn, each row consists of `block` identical thin (one pixel tall) lines. Prepare them for even and odd rows; just two.

```
    line_t even_line = prepare_even_line(block_size);
    line_t odd_line = prepare_odd_line(block_size);
```

and use as in

```
    void emit_row(line_t& line) {
        for (int i = 0; i < block_size; i++) {
            emit_line(line);
        }
    }
```

Now you can

```
    for (row_pair = 0; row_pair < dim / 2; row_pair++) {
        emit_row(even_line);
        emit_row(odd_line);
    }
```

The only thing left is to figure out what `line_t` should be, and how to prepare a thin line. `emit` shall be self evident.